# BigQuery: Most popular NPM packages in GitHub

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In the past I was using the following for extracting the most popular NPM packages in GitHub:
https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/github-bigquery-npm-packages

Unfortunately, Google has removed the JS() function and now I can not "emit" lines.
How can it be done now?

```sql
SELECT package, COUNT(*) as imports
FROM JS(
    (
        SELECT content
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_contents`
        WHERE id IN (
            SELECT id FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_files`
            WHERE LAST(SPLIT(files.path, '/')) = "package.json"
        )
    ),
    content,
    "[{ name: 'package', type: 'string'}]",
    "function(rowData, emit) {
        try {
            content = JSON.parse(rowData.content);
            if (content.dependencies) {
                Object.keys(content.dependencies).forEach((package) => {
                    emit({ package: package });
                });
            }
        } catch(e) {}     
    }"
)
GROUP BY package
ORDER BY imports DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: what you mean by "Google removed"? it is still available with Legacy SQL

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I can not use it - BigQuery is just telling me the code is incorrect. Also, I want to know what is the updated way to do it.

Comment: You might present us with fragment of not working code

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Sure. Added. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and as @Mikhail said, if you [change the SQL dialect](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#changing_from_the_default_dialect) in BigQuery to Legacy SQL, the JS function gets correctly recognized.